# Accessing an input element embeded in an HTML table through VBA

Tags: html, vba, dom, html-table

I've looked around and I'm not sure this question has been asked before.  I think I'm onto the beginning of a solution but here is my issue.  I have an HTML table on a web page that has an input element built into it and I need to access it through VBA.  Here is the relevant snippet of the HTML:

`<td class="tbl1"><input size="11" type="text" maxlength="9" name="txtCusipNo" value=''><a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.open('/SecFinderII1/SIM_SeekSearch.jsp?clientobjectreference=frmSearchEntry.txtCusipNo&formname=frmSearchEntry&textboxname=txtCusipNo','SecurityFinder','resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=no');"><img src="/Settlement/static/images/pbs/lookup.gif" border="0" alt="Open Security Finder" align="absmiddle"></a>&nbsp;<img name="imgCusipNo" src="/Settlement/static/images/pbs/req.gif" border="0" align="top"></td>`

I can find this cell easily enough using the following code:

```
Set Cells = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("td")
For Each Cell In Cells
    If Cell.className = "tbl1" And Cell.something = something Then
        'This is the cell
    End If
Next Cell
```

There are only 5 cells on the page, so no big deal.  What I still need to do is to figure out how to use the input element.  I guess through get child or something?  Can't seem to find any leads on that...

Answer (score 1):

Try [InvokeMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5b41b0d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Set Cells = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("td")
For Each Cell In Cells
    If Cell.className = "tbl1" And Cell.something = something Then
        Cell.InvokeMember("click")
    End If
Next Cell
```